# How to get Attributes of a Group of Default Attribute Set in my custom phtml in Magento_Catalog module

Tags: magento2, php, error, product-attribute

How to get Attributes of a Group of Default Attribute Set in my custom phtml in `Magento_Catalog` module.

using following code

*catalog_product_view.xml*:

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\abstractView" name="product_view_custom_features"
        template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/features.phtml" before="-"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

*template*:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();
        $group_id=9;
        $attributeSetId=4;
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isInGroup($attributeSetId, $group_id)) {
             echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product).'<br />';
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you fix the typo:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$productAttributes=$_product->getAttributes();
        $group_id=9;
        $attributeSetId=4;
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isInGroup($attributeSetId, $group_id)) {
             echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br />';
            }

    }
```